# groovy beginner- how to remove a variable from memory in groovy shell

Tags: groovy, groovyshell

I could not see any method to remove a variable from memory in Groovy shell... is this possible? How do I do this? I can see methods for doings this in Beanshell and Javascript(Rhino) but not in Groovy.

Answer (score 10):

I believe you can do:

```
binding.variables.remove 'varname'
```

Or, if you want to remove all variables, then

```
purge variables
```

should work as well